# Java ternary operator and NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

hi，I encountered a problem in works，the question like this:

```
Integer test1=null;
Integer test2=null;
```

i call them like this:

```
test2=(test1==null?test1:(test1+1));
test2=(test1==null?test1:-1);
```

then the java throw a NullPointerException,so iwrite another code like this:

```
test2=(test1==null?test1:test1);
```

this code is ok.

but,why?

Comment: @Heuster Exactly, and the answer is a) entirely non-obvious and b) very hard to google for.

Comment: Look out for the rules in [JLS Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) as to how the expression is evaluated.

Comment: @Rohit Jain,thanks for your answer,i know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here

```
test2=(test1==null?test1:(test1+1));
```

the expression is going to return an `int`, not an `Integer`.

So the JVM will unbox `test1`, and later box the result. If you unbox a `null`, it will throw an NPE.

e.g. try this:

```
    Integer a = null;
    int b = a;
```

You'll get an NPE at the second line. *But surely this is a simple integer assignment!?* Not so. It's unboxing the null.

I would strongly advise against mixing `Integers` and `int` when `null` is involved. It is a **complete nightmare** to resolve these issues (I'm looking at such stuff right now involving method calls returning `ints` and `Integers`, and passing null around. A simple method return blows up unexpectedly).

If you have an 'optional' integer result, then I would recommend *not* using null, and rather some sort of [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

```
test2=(test1==null?test1:(test1+1));
```

is equivalent to

```
   if(test1==null)
{
    test2 = test1;
}

else{

   test2 = test1 + 1;    
}
```

Please note you can never do any operation on null (Here you are doing test1 + 1 which is equivalent to null + 1  . Hence the Null Pointer Exception)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Well, this is not what's happening here. Since `test1` is `null`, your `if-else` block would not throw `NPE`, whereas, it does in the conditional operator case.

Comment: I wrote this just to explain him the case

Comment: I am sorry i shouldn't have used 'equivalent to'

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
test2=(test1==null?test1: new Integer(test1+1));
test2=(test1==null?test1: new Integer(-1));
```